# IE8 won't load my CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, modernizr

I know this has been asked before, but this case doesn't apply to the other ones.

Here is the site: [link](http://www.adammureiko.com/).

Internet Explorer 8 doesn't want to load the stylesheets.  I've tried using Modernizr (although I may be using it wrong).  I've tried adding this code in my head:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Works fine in everything else, of course.

I'm sure it has something to do with HTML5 and CSS3...
Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use IE. That's a valid suggestion.

Comment: Well, you are loading javascript not css in your example, perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: @DevlshOne No, it is not, because he may have users who use IE.

Comment: I said it was a "valid" suggestion, not a "practical" one. Ease up, Jordo.

Comment: _IE8 and less_ **doesn't support CSS3**.

Comment: Use `<!--[if IE le 8]>` to ensure that your conditional comment only tagets IE8 and lower. You don't need html5shiv for IE9 or later.

Comment: That was just something I tried on the side.  I used a typical '<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />' to attach it in the <head>

Comment: Make the users download the current version of IE or some other browser. Example, `<!--[if lte IE 8]><meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://browsehappy.com/"><![endif]-->`

Comment: @Spudley Hey, it didn't work.  It just showed the markup in the browser like it was just plain text.

Comment: @Vucko that could work too, I guess. Seems like all my problems are IE8 related.

Comment: ah, `lte` not `le`... my mistake.  :)  Anyway, that was just a small part of the problem, not the main issue; I've posted an answer that deals with the main issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why none of your CSS is loading is that your stylesheet uses media queries.

Media queries are not supported by IE8.

You're using a few other unsupported features too, but the media queries are the main ones, because pretty much your entire CSS code is included in one media query block or another, and IE8 won't understand any of it.

To fix this, you should change the way you do media queries. You should have a default set of styles that apply even without any media query at all, and then only use media queries to override them for specific page sizes.

This will allow your CSS to work for older browsers that don't support media queries like IE8. In the browsers, you may get layout issues if the screen size is wrong for your defaults, but if you set sensible defaults, that shouldn't be a big issue.

There are polyfill scripts that will add support for media queries to IE8, such as [respond.js]](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), but if you're using sensible defaults you shouldn't need to use them. (they're great if you do need them, but they can have a negative performance impact, so if you can get away without them it's better)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire stylesheet (style.css) is composed of media queries. Media queries will not work in IE8 even with html5shiv unless you use [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).